# Jquery Table rows to an array containing an array of td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to create an array of table rows containing each td in an array of strings.

Comment: please post sample html / javascript with what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your td's in a string? If so you can try this:

container:

```
<div id="div1" ></div>
```

code:

```
    var datahtml = "<table id='mytable'><tr><th>First Id</th><th>Second</th></tr><tr><td>123</td>    <td>some val</td>  </tr>  <tr>    <td>456</td>    <td></td>  </tr>  <tr><td>789</td>    <td>another one</td>  </tr></table>";


        $('#div1').append($(datahtml));

        $('#mytable').each(function(index, tr) {
            var res = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {
                return $(td).text();

            });
      alert(JSON.stringify(res));//your td's     
  });
```